# How can i get a WYSIWYG Text Area for TypeScript/Angular2/Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, typescript

Is there a  WYSIWYG Text Area for typescript that i can use? I am searching for days but i cant fine a good one. Either i have to pay or no results.

Any suggestions or links are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will [this](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg) or [this](http://ngmodules.org/tags/wysiwyg) help you?

Comment: [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor) has a WYSIWYG editor for Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the summernote WYSIWYG and the [summernote definition file for TypeScript](https://github.com/wstaelens/TypeScript-Summernote).